# Usage of the word ''sillage''

Tags: vocabulary

If someone has a strong sillage it means that their scent remains strongly in their wake.

But can sillage be used to mean ''influence'' or any other abstract meaning ?

Comment: Creative writers do take a _poetic_ license of sorts at times by stretching the most general meanings of words to other related but remote meanings. By the way, *wiktionary* gives one meaning of this word as *slipstream*, which is infact closer to _influence_ than *sillage* itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the three definitions I could find:

1. Wake (the path left behind a ship on the surface of the water)
2. Trail (scent left behind by one who wears perfume)
3. Slipstream (The low-pressure zone immediately following a rapidly moving object, caused by turbulence.)

All three of them mean pretty much the same, contextually. It's what they're leaving in their wake, not what's being done with what they're leaving.

Long story short, you can't use influence for sillage.

If you know programming, then think of Sillage like an event, and 'influence' as one of its methods you can call.

Sillage can do many things(methods in programming). It can leave an impression, good or bad. It can influence, positively or negatively, and so and so forth.

If you want to use Sillage abstractly, you can use simlies to mean it however you want, right?